# Record a video for a long period of time and only keep the last 3 minutes of it

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, video-recording

I want to have a recording session run for around an hour or so, but only keep the current last 3 minutes of the video.

I'm am able to use AVCaptureSession to record and save videos, but I can only manage to save the entire file. I just want the current, last 3 minutes.

This is the gist of the approach I am currently starting with:

```
videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

captureSession!.addOutput(videoFileOutput)

videoFileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(filePath, recordingDelegate: self)
```

Just throwing this out there to see if anyone can point me in the right direction. I can't seem to find anything on the internet myself. Maybe it's not even possible...

Comment: Record this as a sequel of one second fragments and store that in a LRU list ? Then "concat" those 180 seconds to one file ?

Comment: Yes, I've certainly thought about that approach. I may have to end up resorting to that, but I would like to explore other options, if there are any. Thank you for your input! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are no other options. This truly is the only way, since the API doesn't support this directly.